# How to convert UnicodeString to windows-1251 using ICU library in c++ Linux?

Tags: c++, unicode, icu, unicode-string

I have this code, which convert UTF-8 string to Unicode:

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
//included other header files

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string s("some string");
        // convert std::string to ICU's UnicodeString
        UnicodeString ucs = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(s.c_str()));

        // convert UnicodeString to std::wstring
        std::wstring ws;
        for (int i = 0; i < ucs.length(); ++i)
            ws += static_cast<wchar_t>(ucs[i]);

        std::wcout << ws;
}
```

I can not understand how to convert this UnicodeString to windows-1251 (cp1251). Which function shoud I use to do this in Linux ?

Comment: On Windows just use: `MultiByteToWideChar` with the relevant code pages https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx  to convert directly from UTF-8 to cp1251.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I need to do this in Linux, I corrected my question.

Comment: Wikipedia [1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) has the Unicode to/from 1251 mapping.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer, sorry. How exactly can I convert this Unicode string to Windows-1251 ?

Comment: @RichardCritten: you can't convert *directly* from UTF-8 to CP1251 using `MultiByteToWideChar()`. You have to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 first, and then convert UTF-16 to CP1251 using `WideCharToMultiByte()`

Answer (score 5):

Use ICU's conversion functions in `ucnv.h` (see [Conversion > Using Converters](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/converters) in ICU's documentation):

```
#include <memory>
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
bool convertTo1251(std::vector<UChar> const & input, std::vector<char> & output)
{
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    UConverter *pConvert = ucnv_open("windows-1251", &status);
    if (status)
    {
        printf("Failed to obtain char set converter: %d\r\n", status);
        return false;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<UConverter> cnv(pConvert, ucnv_close);

    UChar const * pwszBegin = &input[0], *pwszEnd = pwszBegin + input.size();
    output.resize(input.size());

    char *pszBegin = &output[0], *pszEnd = pszBegin + input.size();

    ucnv_fromUnicode(pConvert, &pszBegin, pszEnd, &pwszBegin, pwszEnd, nullptr, true, &status);
    if (status)
    {
        // deal with error
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So much boilerplate for such a simple task!

Comment: The boilerplate appears to be almost entirely due to C's lack of exceptions and destructors. If someone made a C++ wrapper, then it appears that this becomes two lines of code. One to open the converter, and one to convert the string.

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5776835dad913326 With appropriate C++ wrappers around everything, it becomes `return fromUnicode(uconverter_map.get_or_open("windows-1251"), input);`. This is also faster, since I'm caching the converters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standalone function [from here](https://github.com/0x1801/REPA/blob/main/utf8_2_win1251.c):

```
/* Функция конвертирует utf8 строку в win 1251. Символы, не имеющие отображения, или переходят в 0x98 или пропускаются. 
   Вариант работы выбирается версией макроса SKIP_OR_NOT. 
   Входной массив может совпадать с выходным: данные будут перезаписаны. 
   ВНИМАНИЕ: массив utf8 должен быть выделен с запасом по памяти в 2 байта. Т.е. за символом конца строки '\0' должно быть как минимум 2 байта памяти. 
   В этих 2х байтах может лежать любой муcор. В противном случае программа может падать из-за доступа к не своей памяти. 
   Функция полностью независима и не требует ничего, кроме тройки макросов ниже. В том числе не требует никаких инклюдов. 
   Для использования просто скопируйте ее код вместе с 3мя макросами. 
   Не использует SIMD и даже x64, потому подходит для многих архитектур и даже для микроконтроллеров, т.к. ест мало памяти.
   Связаться с автором: Илья chronosphere@mail.ru. Любой может использовать данный код для любых целей. 
   Просьба только не удалять ссылку на автора при копировании.*/
#define NONS (0x98)
//#define SKIP_OR_NOT 1
#define SKIP_OR_NOT (dest != NONS)
#define M(W40, W45, W201) ((((W40) - 0x80) << 10) | (((W45) - (W40)) << 5) | ((W201) - 0x80))
unsigned int utf8_2_win1251(const char *utf8, char *win)
{
    unsigned int dest, p, l1, l2, l3, inc, i, j, b1, b2, b3;
    const unsigned short AR[16] = { M(NONS,NONS,0x86),M(0xA8,0xB8,0x87),M(0x80,0x90,0x95),M(0x81,0x83,0x96),
                                    M(0xAA,0xBA,0x97),M(0xBD,0xBE,NONS),M(0xB2,0xB3,NONS),M(0xAF,0xBF,NONS),
                                    M(0xA3,0xBC,0x91),M(0x8A,0x9A,0x92),M(0x8C,0x9C,0x82),M(0x8E,0x9E,NONS),
                                    M(0x8D,0x9D,0x93),M(NONS,NONS,0x94),M(0xA1,0xA2,0x84),M(0x8F,0x9F,NONS) };
    for (i = 0, j = 0; utf8[i] != 0; i += inc)
    {
        b1 = utf8[i]; b2 = utf8[i + 1]; b3 = utf8[i + 2];
        /* Utf8 переводим в Unicode. */
        inc = (0xE5000000u >> (((b1) >> 4) << 1)) & 0x3;
        p = ((((b1) << 12) + (((b2) & 0x3F) << 6) + ((b3) & 0x3F)) & (0x7FFFF >> inc)) >> (((0xC5FFAAAAu >> (((b1) >> 4) << 1)) & 0x3) * 6);
        /* Добавляем все остающиеся на месте. */
        dest = (((inc != 0) & (((p >> 5) != 0x5) | (0xF71C852E >> b2))) - 1) & p; inc++;
        /* Добавляем русские буквы кроме ё и Ё.*/
        dest += ((((p - 0x10) >> 6) != 0x10) - 1) & (p - 0x350);
        /* Добавляем символы из диапазонов: 0x401-0x40F, 0x451-0x45F, 0x2013-0x2022. */
        l1 = ((p >> 4) != 0x40) - 1; l2 = ((p >> 4) != 0x45) - 1; l3 = (((p - 3) >> 4) != 0x201) - 1;
        dest += ((((l2 & (AR[p & 0xF] >> 5)) | (l3 & AR[p & 0xF])) & 0x1F) + ((l1 | l2) & (AR[p & 0xF] >> 10))) + ((l1 | l2 | l3) & 0x80);
        /* Добавляем оставшиеся. */
        dest += (((p !=  0x490) - 1) & 0xA5) | (((p !=  0x491) - 1) & 0xB4) | (((p != 0x2026) - 1) & 0x85) |
                (((p != 0x2030) - 1) & 0x89) | (((p != 0x2039) - 1) & 0x8B) | (((p != 0x203A) - 1) & 0x9B) |
                (((p != 0x20AC) - 1) & 0x88) | (((p != 0x2116) - 1) & 0xB9) | (((p != 0x2122) - 1) & 0x99);
        /* Отличаем настоящий 0 от просто отсутствующих в win 1251 символов. */
        dest += (((b1 == 0) | (dest != 0)) - 1) & NONS;
        win[j] = dest;
        j += SKIP_OR_NOT;
    }
    win[j] = 0;
    return j;
}
#undef M
#undef NONS
#undef SKIP_OR_NOT
```